# System cannot find help file

Tags: c#, .net, path

I am developing a c# desktop application and I have a help.chm file. 
I want to give a path to my program, and after I publish and run it on another pc, use that help.chm file.

What is the correct approach for something like that to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you are deploying the application, but generally you can directly access a file in the same directory as the executable.

Comment: I use this snippet but nothing works  string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
            path = "file://" + Path.Combine(path, "yardim.chm");
            Help.ShowHelp(this, path);